# Trying to find the smallest number in a 2D array using recursion

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find the smallest number in a 2D (pointer to pointer) array using recursion, here is the code so far:

```
int smallest(int **arr, int row_size, int column_size)
{   
    if (row_size == 0 && column_size == 0)
    {
        return *(*(arr + 0) + 0);
    }

    row_size--;
    column_size--;

    if ((*(*(arr + 0) + 0)) < (*(*arr + row_size) + column_size))
    {
        return smallest(arr, row_size, column_size);
    }
    else
    {
        *(*(arr + 0) + 0) = *(*(arr + row_size) + column_size);
        return smallest(arr, row_size, column_size);
    }
}
```

**This works but has 2 drawbacks:**

**1-** Only processes square arrays.

**2-** Only processes indexes where row & column numbers are the same (such as 1,1 2,2 & 3,3 etc.)

I'm trying to make it process non-square arrays as well but that would require decrementing rows and column numbers at different times, I'm not sure how to go about that. Any clues?

Comment: You don't need recursion to loop a 2D array, since you know the size

Comment: @Cid This problem is way easier with loops but I have to use recursion as it is necessary in this case.

Comment: As a suggestion you can use the subscript operator `[]` to access elements of an array.
Technically `address[offset]` is equivalent to `*(address + offset)` but it's more readable

Comment: Why the `*(*(arr + x) + y)` dance instead of `arr[x][y]`?

Comment: @Lorand Yes correct but using pointer notations for nearly everything is a question requirement as well.

Comment: @Quentin Question requirement.

Comment: It's surprising that searching for the minimum value in a matrix modifies the matrix.

Comment: My condolences. I hope whatever course you're taking won't disgust you from (actual) C++!

Comment: you can find `min` in every column, then find the smallest within them.

Comment: @appleapple elabroate a little bit :(

Comment: "Proper"  use of recusion usually reduce the task to _several_ smaller tasks. Typically, you would let your function divide the array into four smaller arrays, call itself recursively on each and return the smallest of the results. (Unless the input array only has one element, in which case you return that element)

Comment: Silly task, so a silly solution would be to write a solution with normal loops and then turn those loops into tail recursive loops. I suspect that this is what your professor is expecting anyway, anything else would be really stupid.

Comment: @Idaisa I found out you can use one simple recursion function, see my answer. what I described in previous comment is possible with 2 function or 1 function with branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assumed requirements**:

- Cannot modify function signature (can be simpler if this is not the case)
- Can only have a **single** function (ditto)
- Must be purely recursive (i.e. no loops)
- Must use pointer dereferencing (`*(arr + 1)` instead of `arr[1]`)

**Procedure**:

- Recurse through the first row only (setting `rows` to 1)
- Recurse through all *other* rows (decrement `rows`)

**Code**:

```
int smallest(int **arr, int rows, int columns)
{   
    // invalid input
    if (rows <= 0 || columns <= 0)
        return INT_MAX;

    // top-left element
    int m = **arr;

    // single row recursion
    if (rows == 1) {
        *arr++; // increment the temporary pointer from below
        return min(m, smallest(arr, 1, columns - 1));
    }

    // create a temporary pointer to the first row
    // and start recursion in this single row
    int* row = *arr;
    m = min(m, smallest(&row, 1, columns));

    // rest of array
    return min(m, smallest(arr + 1, rows, columns - 1));
}
```

---

**EDIT**: since you are allowed to modify the function signature, you can add an extra index for looping through each row; this removes the need for that extra temporary pointer.

```
int smallest(int **arr, int rows, int columns, int column_index = 0)
{   
    // invalid input
    if (rows <= 0 || column_index >= columns)
        return INT_MAX;

    // single row recursion
    if (rows == 1)
        return min(*(*arr + column_index),       // first element of row
                   smallest(arr, 1, columns - 1, 
                            column_index + 1));  // rest of row

    // rest of array
    return min(smallest(arr, 1, columns),        // start on first row
               smallest(arr + 1, rows - 1, columns));
}
```

Note that external call signatures can still be the same as before due to the default argument value.

Comment: I think this is the answer I'm looking for, really appreciate the writing of such clean code with comments explaining what each snippet does. We can however modify the function signature, is it possible to make it more simple somehow if we do that? If so, what would your approach be? :) I don't understand any of the other answers as they are using limits, boosts and constant pointers, none of which we have covered so far.

Comment: @Idaisa if it's possible to modify the function signature, sure it can be simpler. I'll update.

Comment: That woud be very nice of you!

Comment: very elegant solution, appreciate it :) Do you think it would be simpler or "better" if we could use more than one function?

Comment: @Idaisa yes it would be nice to have a separate function just for the rows; that said, nothing beats a good old for loop :) Also I had assumed you would not be allowed another function due to the pointer dereferencing rule.

Answer (score 1):

not tested, but I think it would work.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

//call with row = row_size-1, column = column_size -1
int smallest(int **arr, int row, int column)
{
    if( row<0 || column<0 )return std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    return std::min( {arr[row][column], smallest(arr,row-1,column), smallest(arr,row,column-1)} );
}
```

---

The recursion is

[image]

Comment: We have not covered <algorithms> and <limits> so I don't really understand this and therefore can't use it. :(

Comment: `<algorithm>` is include for `min` it's easy to implement it yourself, and `<limits>` is for `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` which is simply the largest int, you can replace it as any number that is very large, say, `100000000`.

Comment: Wouldn't this have exponential time complexity, since you are processing the rest of the array **twice**? (everything apart from the current column / row)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog yeah, I believe it would be pretty complex, and can be resolve with memory(DP). Anyway, solve this with pure recursion is itself not really efficient :)

Comment: My point is, there is a difference between using a fundamentally more efficient algorithm and optimizing the implementation of it.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog A fundamentally more efficient algorithm? why use recursion at first place?

Comment: By fundamentally I meant time-complexity, not implementation details. Recursion is still O(mn). But... as long as it works, eh? :)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog simplicity is soul of recursion (in my opinion), and this algorithm is simple. just like those example of recursion fibonacci, efficiency may not be a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Bored professionals overkill introductory problems, volume 3! This version:

- Uses a secondary function to traverse each row (that might be off-limits of the question's rules, but you can combine them and switch on whether the pointers array has only one row)
- Works with empty arrays (and returns the maximal value of an `int`)
- Does not use index notation
- Is purely recursive

```
int smallest(int const * const array, int const length) {
    return length == 0
        ? std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
        : std::min(*array, smallest(array + 1, length - 1));
}

int smallest(int const * const * const array, int const rows, int const columns) {
    return rows == 0
        ? std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
        : std::min(
            smallest(*array, columns),             // Minimum from the current row
            smallest(array + 1, rows - 1, columns) // Minimum from the rest of the rows
        );
}
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/540ab20b8ebcb859)

Comment: "Bored professionals overkill introductory problems, volume 3!" :D

Comment: Where can I subscribe? :)

Comment: This is likely very good solution to the problem but I wouldn't know because haven't covered const * const * pointers and <int> etc. type of things.

Comment: @Idaisa `const` is declaring the variables as read-only, but you can remove them all if you haven't covered this yet. You may replace `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` with the macro `INT_MAX` from `#include <climits>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can get away without recursion, if this is a purely learning excercise for recursion you could try [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) approach.
Have an entry point to start your search `(i,j)`, from each point exhaust all possible areas you could go, `(i+1,j)(i-1,j)(i,j+1)(i,j-1)`. Each recursion step would also check if you are in within the limits of the array which would be `i < 0 || i >= rows || j < 0 || j >= cols || visited[i][j]` you would just return at this point.

Notice the `visited` array. So at each point in the recursion there could be a chance that you return back to the same cell right? that would make it an infinite recrusion to avoid this, you track which cells you have already visited, `visited[i][j]`. Mark them. Each recrusion call keep track of the minimum element recorded by reference, which will be your minimum element.

```
void findMinElement(vector<vector<int>>& array, int& minelement, int i, int j, vector<vector<bool>>& visited)
{
    if(i < 0 || i >= array.size() || j < 0 || j >= array[0].size() || visited[i][j]) return;

    minelement = min(minelement,array[i][j]); // is this the best minimum?

    visited[i][j] = true; // done visiting this cell

    //lets visits others
    findMinElement(array, minelement, i+1, j, visited);
    findMinElement(array, minelement, i-1, j, visited);
    findMinElement(array, minelement, i, j+1, visited);
    findMinElement(array, minelement, i, j-1, visited);
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> array =
    {
        {9,8,6,4},
        {13,4,6,11},
        {3,8,3,100}
    };

    int minElement = INT32_MAX;
    //same dimensions as array
    vector<vector<bool>> visited(array.size(), vector<bool>(array[0].size(),false));
    //start from (0,0)
    findMinElement(array,minElement,0,0,visited);
    cout << minElement;
}
```

This now gives you the flexibility to start searching from any location in the array as well. It might be a bit to take in, but it will help you with many problems further down the line.

Comment: unnecessarily complex,  simple `from 0 to n` just have the same effect.

Comment: I don't think so, introduces you to other concepts as well, Let me post an example.

Comment: @SamerTufail Appreciate the answer but we have not studied <vector> and <bool> and such things. :(

Comment: @Idaisa no problem, I thought you wouldn't have, I just wanted to explain the algorithm rather than language syntax, so vector is your array, and visited is another array same size of type bool.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass the matrix bounds to the function so you can "move" in one dimension when you reach the end of the other.

Something like this (I find it more natural to count upwards than downwards):

```
int smallest(int **arr, int row, int column, int row_last, int column_last)
{   
    if (row == row_last && column == column_last)
    {
        return arr[row][column];
    }
    else if (column == column_last)
    {
        return min(arr[row][column], smallest(arr, row+1, 0, row_last, column_last));
    }
    else
    {
        return min(arr[row][column], smallest(arr, row, column+1, row_last, column_last));
    }
}
```

(This is one of those exercises that introduces potentially useful concepts in a situation where they don't serve any purpose. It's not a good use of either recursion or pointer arithmetic.)

Comment: Hey can elaborate if possible what does row_last and column_last imply here as we are already passing the row size and column size through the function? :)

Comment: The `row` and `column` parameters are your "current state" - they change in each function invocation. The `*_last` parameters are the dimensions (actually the last valid index), because you need to know the boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't help myself. This is an implementation that will divide the input array into four smaller arrays and calls iself on them (unless they are zero size):

```
int smallest(int **arr, int row_begin, int row_end, int column_begin, int column_end)
{
    if (row_end - row_begin == 1 && column_end - column_begin == 1) return *(*(arr + row_begin) + column_begin);

    int row_mid = (row_begin + row_end) / 2;
    int column_mid = (column_begin + column_end) / 2;

    int minimum = smallest(arr, row_mid, row_end, column_mid, column_end);
    if (column_mid > column_begin) {
        int m = smallest(arr, row_mid, row_end, column_begin, column_mid);
        if (m < minimum) minimum = m;
    }
    if (row_mid > row_begin) {
        int m = smallest(arr, row_begin, row_mid, column_begin, column_end);
        if (m < minimum) minimum = m;
    }
    if (column_mid > column_begin && row_mid > row_begin) {
        int m = smallest(arr, row_begin, row_mid, column_begin, column_mid);
        if (m < minimum) minimum = m;
    }
    return minimum;
}
```

Call it like this:
    cout << smallest(test_array, 0, rows, 0, columns);

Comment: This seems like an interesting approach, I'll try to understand it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
int smallest(int **arr, int row_size, int column_size)
{
if (row_size > 0 && column_size > 0)
{
int minRow = arr[0][0];

for (int j = 0; j < row_size; ++j)
{
const int *row = arr[j];
minRow = std::min(minRow, *std::min_element(row, row + column_size));
}
return minRow;
}
else return INT_MAX;
}
```